# create infopath form which receives data from web service and save it in sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, infopath-forms-services

I have create a web service using WCF and I want to display, let's say the details of a company in the infopath. After I make the modifications, I would like to save it in sharepoint library. Once I save it there then I what I want is that when I click on one of the links in sharepoint I would like to open it and display the details in infopath again.

Can anyone help me with this?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within InfoPath if you select the "Web Service" advanced form template you can set your web service as the main connection. You'll then be able to pull information from the web service.

In order to submit to a Sharepoint Library you just need to add a button to your form, edit its properties select "Submit" under action, then click "Submit options...". From here you will select the "Send form data to a single destination" radio button and use the drop down to select SharePoint document library. From here just follow through the wizard and you should have a functioning form.